# Parsing dates and times from a large string into seperate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse the date and time from a string column.

This is the original column (all one column):

```
description 
4/18/2020 21:05  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

my desired output:

```
spliced_date       spliced_time
4/18/2020          21:05
```

I am looking to pick out the date and time into their own seperate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['4/18/2020 21:05  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ']})
df[['Date','Time']] = df['description'].str.split(n=2, expand=True)[[0,1]]
df = df.drop(columns='description')
```

Output:

```
        Date   Time
0  4/18/2020  21:05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use named capture group with `str.extract`:

```
pattern = r'(?P<spliced_date>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<spliced_time>[^\s]+)'
df = df['description'].str.extract(pattern)
print(df)

# Output:
  spliced_date spliced_time
0    4/18/2020        21:05
```